# How to add tooltip for event of fullcalendar 3.9 / bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I with fullcalendar 3.9.0 in my Laravel 8 /  jQuery 3.5.1 / bootstrap  4.5.3 app I want to add  tooltip
for title of event item in method

```
eventRender: function (eventInfo, element, view) {
    ...
```

In bootstrap tooltip is added with props:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Right</button>
```

I wonder if there a way to assign properties data-toggle, data-placement, data-original-title to element
of event, which has output in the console : https://prnt.sc/wjndg3

If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: No, but you can initialise the tooltip via JavaScript code instead, as per bootstrap documentation

Comment: See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#usage for details

Comment: Thanks, but how it can be assigned to element(second parameter of eventRender) ?

Comment: Just the normal way. Actually, as per fullCalendar 3 docs, `element` is already a jQuery object, so you should be able to just write e.g. `element.tooltip(options);` (where `options` is an object containing the tooltip settings).

Comment: No I got TypeError: element.tooltip is not a function error . Look at this https://prnt.sc/wjndg3 printscerrn what element is.

Comment: The console log indicates that the element is a jQuery object. That error means you didn't include the correct bootstrap JS file in the page

Comment: If you include the correct file then it works fine. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwGYMPL